# Printing WebView contents on a Bluetooth printer

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth, android-webview, android-bluetooth

I'm using following code from [developer site](https://developer.android.com/training/printing/html-docs.html) to print web-view to Bluetooth printer from android app.

```
 private void createWebPrintJob(WebView webView) {

    PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) this
          .getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);

    PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter = 
             webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter();

    String jobName = getString(R.string.app_name) + 
                        " Print Test";

    printManager.print(jobName, printAdapter,
           new PrintAttributes.Builder().build());
}
```

But It loads webview and ask to save as PDF, instead of showing Bluetooth printers available. Even if we search for printers it is searching for long time with no result.

So please suggest me someway to  the dynamic HTML content or webview to Bluetooth printer.

Comment: In later version of Android (I think N+) if there is at least one printer found it will be automatically selected instead of PDF. The problem is that the printer is not found. Do you have a Print Service installed that supports this printer?

Comment: I am not finding any print service available for Itermec 6820 series. Now I need to format everything as service not available?

Comment: Have you tried sharing the content to the printer as a bluetooth peripheral? If that works, it should be easy to implement it. You may want to contact the manufacturer to see if they support printing from Android devices

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I sorted it out and will answer it here. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code works if you have a supported plugin service available in the playstore. Unfortunately the printer(Intermec 6820 series) doesn't have any. So I ended up formatting the text using android `String.format` and printing it out.